# Бот ВК не хочет отвечать на сообщения, что делать? Опять ВК всё поменяли?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Давно не занимался ботом, сегодня решил вспомнить. Видимо ВК что-то опять поменяли или я просто не понимаю. Проблема в том, что бот не хочет отвечать на сообщение.

```
        request = event.object.get('text')
        peer_id = event.object.get('peer_id')
        chat_id = event.chat_id

        if request == "1":
            write_msg(vk, chat_id, '2')
```

Бот должен увидеть `"1"` и ответить цифрой `"2"`, но бот этого не делает.

Решил проверить, видит ли бот вовсе сообщения.

```
for event in longpoll.listen():

    print(event)
```

`>>>  <<class 'vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotMessageEvent'>({'type': 'message_new', 'object': {'message': {'date': 1591555409, 'from_id': 154845243, 'id': 0, 'out': 0, 'peer_id': 2000000001, 'text': '1', 'conversation_message_id': 3911, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'random_id': 0, 'attachments': [], 'is_hidden': False}, 'client_info': {'button_actions': ['text', 'vkpay', 'open_app', 'location', 'open_link'], 'keyboard': True, 'inline_keyboard': True, 'lang_id': 0}}, 'group_id': 180942478, 'event_id': 'f9728518e78af89a8bff4c956e0102dfc1c1fa8f'})>>`

Работаю с Longpoll, все события включил, при создании ключа всё тоже включил.

Полный код:

```
for event in longpoll.listen():

    print(event)

    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:

        request = event.object.get('text')
        peer_id = event.object.get('peer_id')
        chat_id = event.chat_id

        if request == "1":
            write_msg(vk, chat_id, '2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно извлекаете информацию из полученного события

```
request = event['object']['message']['text']
peer_id = event['object']['message']['peer_id']
chat_id - такого параметра в вашем выводе вообще не существует.
```

write_msg это функция? если нет, то она у вас попросту не будет работать